# Access 97 to 2003 conversion loses MSCOMCTL.OCX

Tags: ms-access, ms-office

I am in the process of migrating my Access97 FE to 2003.  For a while now I've been compiling both a 97 front end and a 2003 front end (97 for my XP machines, 2003 for my Win7 machines).  Just recently (in the last week?).. I start losing my MSCOMCTL.OCX reference when converting.  However, the odd thing is it only happens on my Windows 7 (32 bit) machine running Office 2003 (SP3).  If I convert it on another Win7 64 bit, Office 2003 (SP3) machine I don't lose the referenced file.

I've registered/unregistered C:\windows\system32\mscomctl.ocx several times now (making sure to run command prompt as administrator).. and restarting.  I've uninstalled Office 2003 on the troubled machine and re-loaded it to no avail.  I've made sure C:\windows\system32 is in the path.. (it is)

If I compile the FE on my Win7 64-bit machine, and distribute it to this trouble machine it will not start the app properly (gets an initializing bar at the bottom) indefinitely.  If I re-reference the file on the trouble machine and re-create an MDE it works on both the 32bit version and the 64 bit version of Windows 7 (even though the 64 bit has mscomctl.ocx in C:\windows\syswow64)..

Is something wrong with my Win7 32bit setup?  I can take an older version of my FE (I keep a repo as I make changes) and those seem to not lose the reference. The FE in question compiles fine on my Acc97 machines and my Win7 64-bit machines. I used to compile all my 2003 FE's on the "now" troubled Win7 32bit machine... ?

I've run decompile/repair/compile/compact on the MDB file several times as well.

Can anyone suggest something to try?

***UPDATE*** 
Well I blew the "problem" workstation away and reloaded with Win7 Pro 64-bit, this will make WSUS duty easier anyway. However the problem persists... so now I'm not sure what to think.

Comment: I think programmer hell is a place where you are forced to work for  MSCOMCTL comparability issues for eternity. It makes me a little nauseous even seeing the name of that OCX mentioned in print.

Comment: I didn't say I liked it.. that's for sure. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should confirm the version of MSCOMCTL.OCX used by your Access app is the same version used on any machine you might compile it on.  Check which file the reference is using by:

```
Function ListReferences()

    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Long

    a = References.count

    For b = 1 To a
        Debug.Print b & ": " & References(b).Name & vbTab & vbTab & References(b).FullPath
    Next b

End Function
```

This will give you a list of file names and paths for all references in your Access FE.

Use Windows Explorer to locate the MSCOMCTL.OCX referenced by Access.  Right-click the file and note the version.  Confirm the MSCOMCTL.OCX you are using on all other computers is the same version.

Comment: References look pretty sane.  MSCOMCTL.OCX is in C:\windows\syswow64 (Win7 64bit) versus C:\windows\system32 (Win7 32 bit/Win XP 32 bit), but from my understanding Access will check system paths for references on startup?

Comment: As far as I know, Access uses the registry to locate the GUID of the control to then locate the source OCX/DLL file.  I've had this same problem with Access 2003 (in fact all versions); I've always ended up distributing the DLLs and OCXs I need along with the MDB; in fact I wrote a custom setup program in VS.Net 2008 to cope with registering COM DLLs and OCXs, etc.  In short, you really need to make sure the OCX registered in the system registry is the same version on all the machines that will have your MDB file.

Comment: Copy the MSCOMCTL.OCX from your development machine into the syswow64 folder on the machine in question and use REGSVR32.exe to register the ocx file on whatever machine is having the problem.  Oh, and keep your fingers crossed.

Comment: Boom. Nice find! Fixed that headache. How are you distributing your dlls (prior to installer)? Just in the same dir as the FE file and using that reference? I guess that wouldn't solve it not being registered though.

Comment: I have built a lot of my own OCXs and DLLs in VB6, and many in VB.Net.  I put the OCXs and DLLs in the same folder as the MDB (actually I distribute an MDE), and I put the VB.Net DLLs into the `Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11` folder (or whatever folder is appropriate for the version of Access you are using.  I register my own OCXs and DLLs and the VB.Net Dlls don't have to be registered since they are in the same folder as MSAccess.exe

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `MSCOMCTL.OCX` on your machine was replaced by a newer version by an automatic Windows update?

At work, we had problems on some machines with this last week after the automatic installation of [a certain update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2687441/en-us).
Quote from the "Known issues with this security update" section of the above link:

> Windows Common Control-based embedded ActiveX controls may fail to load within pre-existing office documents, within third-party applications, and when you insert new controls in developer mode.

Apparently we were not the only ones having problems:
[After installing KB2687441 Access forms utilizing components from MSCOMCTL.ocx fail to open](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/office2007deploymentcompatibility/thread/7faa69b8-a60a-436b-9058-3f87b9866f47)

Comment: I did see this, however this machine does not have that patch. It was held back in WSUS to avoid this problem.